# Vite+React application exposed on network refreshes on its own in local browser

Tags: reactjs, browser, vite

I have a React application that resides on a remote VM. I have used `vite --host` to host it on the network. While accessing it on a browser inside the VM, it works fine. But when accessing it from my local browser, the page refreshes on its own after some time, which causes the app to lose all its state. What could be the reason for this and any suggestions to fix this?

I'm using `vite 4.4.5`